# “No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.” when adding rows to DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, currencymanager

I'm getting the following message when trying to add rows to a DataTable: “No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.” Interestingly enough, the DataTable that I'm trying to add the row to *does* have three columns at the point when the row is being added. It seems like the failure is occurring on the currency manager, way down in the row-insertion stack. Here's my code:

```
    Using DT As DataTable = Me.Tables(TableNamePrefix & " " & CStr(Index + 1))
        DT.Rows.Clear()
        DT.Columns.Clear()

        For Each LF As cLoadField In LFs
            LF.UseDefaultUnits(DispOpt.Units, DispOpt.Format)
            DT.Columns.Add(LF.Name(Cond)).Caption = LF.Name(Cond)
            If Not LF.UnitString(DispOpt) = "" Then
                DT.Columns(LF.Name(Cond)).Caption = LF.Name(Cond) & vbCrLf & LF.UnitString(DispOpt)
            End If
            If LF.FieldType = hecLoadFields.hecLF_LengthPaidOut Then LPO_Name = LF.Name(Cond)
        Next

        For Each HW As CHawser In Hawsers
            If Not Cond.Loads.NameExists(HW.Name) Then Continue For

            DR = DT.NewRow
            For Each LF As cLoadField In LFs
                LF.TankName = HW.Name
                DR(LF.Name(Cond)) = LF.Value(Cond)
            Next
            DT.Rows.Add(DR)
        Next
    End Using
```

And here's the call stack:

```
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.InsertInternal(int rowIndex, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow, bool force) + 0x342 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.ProcessListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) + 0x5ed bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.currencyManager_ListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) + 0x2b bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.OnListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) + 0x15 bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.List_ListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) + 0x53e bytes   
System.Data.dll!System.Data.DataView.OnListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) + 0x136 bytes  
System.Data.dll!System.Data.DataView.IndexListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) + 0x1c bytes 
System.Data.dll!System.Data.DataView.IndexListChangedInternal(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) + 0x47 bytes    
System.Data.dll!System.Data.DataViewListener.IndexListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) + 0x3b bytes    
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Index.OnListChanged.AnonymousMethod__2(System.Data.DataViewListener listener, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs args, bool arg2, bool arg3) + 0x7 bytes    
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Listeners<System.__Canon>.Notify<System.__Canon,bool,bool>(System.__Canon arg1, bool arg2, bool arg3, System.Data.Listeners<System.__Canon>.Action<System.__Canon,System.__Canon,bool,bool> action) + 0x90 bytes    
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Index.OnListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) + 0xa4 bytes  
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Index.OnListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedType changedType, int index) + 0x38 bytes  
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Index.InsertRecord(int record, bool fireEvent) + 0xdf bytes 
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Index.ApplyChangeAction(int record, int action, int changeRecord) + 0x34 bytes  
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Index.RecordStateChanged(int record, System.Data.DataViewRowState oldState, System.Data.DataViewRowState newState) + 0x40 bytes 
System.Data.dll!System.Data.DataTable.RecordStateChanged(int record1, System.Data.DataViewRowState oldState1, System.Data.DataViewRowState newState1, int record2, System.Data.DataViewRowState oldState2, System.Data.DataViewRowState newState2) + 0xaf bytes 
System.Data.dll!System.Data.DataTable.SetNewRecordWorker(System.Data.DataRow row, int proposedRecord, System.Data.DataRowAction action, bool isInMerge, bool suppressEnsurePropertyChanged, int position, bool fireEvent, out System.Exception deferredException) + 0x540 bytes 
System.Data.dll!System.Data.DataTable.InsertRow(System.Data.DataRow row, long proposedID, int pos, bool fireEvent) + 0xf5 bytes 
System.Data.dll!System.Data.DataRowCollection.Add(System.Data.DataRow row) + 0x1a bytes
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the datatable the datasource of a grid somewhere? Where does the error occur in the code you posted ? Try setting the grids datasource to NOTHING before you run this code. Do you still get the error?

Comment: The datatable is the source of a grid, and I actually found that the issue was related to the grid's AutoGenerateColumns property. If I don't have that set, the datatable passes the columns to the grid, which it doesn't use, and then tries to pass the rows to that column-less grid. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: That's kind of what I was getting around to. Setting the datasource to nothing should also prevent that issue, and some others that you may or may not ever run into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This DataTable is the DataSource of a DataGridView that lives on my application's main form. It turns out that I didn't set the AutoGenerateColumns property of the DataGridView, which was the source of this error.